# Writing text to a cv::gpu::GpuMat

Tags: c++, opencv

We have for CPUs the OpenCV 2.x API:

```
cv::Mat mat;
putText(mat, "hello world!", cv::Point(10, 10), FONT_HERSEY_PLAIN, 1.0,
                                                       cv::Scalar::all(255));
```

But what do we have for `cv::gpu::GpuMat`? What is the canonical solution?

Comment: You can just `upload` the `mat` to a `gpumat`after writing the text

Comment: But that will be destructive, and downloading then uploading doesn't seem that efficient.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a method for `putText` that accepts a `gpumat` as far as I know so that maybe the only method currently

Comment: @EdChum It would appear to be possible to do some sort of efficient (I presume?) combination of `getTextSize`, create a minimal `Mat`, `download` the ROI, `putText`, then `upload`. Or skip the `download` and instead `putText`, `upload` and some sort of copy with mask. That's why I asked for a canonical answer that is both efficient and covers corner cases.